# Ошибка game is not responding.do you want to close it

Tags: android, unity3d

после добавления обновления в игру стала появляться эта ошибка.

Теперь она вылазит как в новом билде так и в старых.

В чем может быть проблема ошибки?

Места на телефоне достаточно. Производились перезагрузки телефона, переустановка, очистка данных. Но ничего не помогает. Я не знаю в какую сторону мне думать. Проблема может быть не в коде ? Может что то сохранилось в PlayerPrefs и теперь мешает от билда к билду ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это означает что главный (он же UI) поток чем-то занят или заблокирован более трёх секунд. Проблема однозначно в коде, но могла не проявляться, так как укладывалась в тайм-аут. Теперь изменилось какое-то условие (коих может быть вагон: от версии движка и системы сборки до загрузки процессора другими приложениями) и перестала укладываться. Конечно, в теории, возможен  баг в движке или системе, но маловероятен - серьёзные качественные продукты тщательно тестируются перед выпуском релиза.

Comment: @woesss можно ли как то отследить это? Что бы найти конкретное место. Из каких-то логов  к примеру

Comment: Критические ошибки, приводящие к остановке приложения, обязательно выводятся в лог - поищите, для ANR должна быть какая-то трассировка, но насчёт отладки юнитов я не советчик.